# databricks secrets create-scope backend-type KEYVAULT must have AzureKeyVaultSecretScopeMetadata defined

Tags: databricks, azure-databricks

I want to create a keyvault-backed secret scope in databricks USING THE CLI.

```
databricks secrets create-scope "keyvault_nonHR_QUA" --scope-backend-type AZURE_KEYVAULT
```

gives me `Error: Scope with Azure KeyVault must have AzureKeyVaultSecretScopeMetadata defined!`

while:

```
databricks secrets create-scope "myscope" --scope-backend-type AZURE_KEYVAULT --resource-id "<azure-keyvault-resource-id>" --dns-name "<azure-keyvault-dns-name>" --initial-manage-principal users
```

gives `Error: unknown flag: --resource-id`

The doc seems to refer to the legacy CLI
[https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/security/secrets/secret-scopes#--create-an-azure-key-vault-backed-secret-scope-using-the-databricks-cli](https://keyvault%20backed%20secret%20scopes)

any help welcome

Comment: What CLI version are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I faced this same issue using `Databricks CLI v0.204.0`.  The only way I found to remedy this was to use the --json flag.

For example...
`databricks secrets create-scope --json "{\"scope\": \"kduenke-testing\", \"scope_backend_type\": \"AZURE_KEYVAULT\", \"backend_azure_keyvault\": { \"resource_id\": \"/subscriptions/<--SUBSCRIPTION_GUID-->/resourceGroups/<--RESOURCE_GROUP_NAME-->/providers/Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults/<--KEY_VAULT_NAME-->\", \"dns_name\": \"https://<--KEY_VAULT_NAME-->.vault.azure.net/\" } }"`